# If we squash the commits into one in Git and rebase, does it really matter that we rebase or merge?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

The reason we rebase is that the history is all linear.  But if we squash the commits into one, does it matter if we just merge and then ignore any branch?

I was talking to a coworker about being able to do binary search if the history is linear and if one developer has 7 commits and 1 commit of the 7 commits introduced a bug, we can find exactly which commit it is using automated binary search (and automated test). But he said what if some intermediate commits is actually not good yet and it may break the build or break the test.  Then he mentioned able to squash all the commits into one and just rebase, then it wouldn't have such a problem of catching a not-so-ready commit.

If we really can use binary search to find which commit introduced a new bug, that's be nice, and we don't have to worry about the history has 7 times more commits, because O(log n) is not an issue when n is increased 7 times -- it just means 3 more build-and-test. But do we really do binary search to find a new bug using automated build and automated test in practice? It seems really time consuming.

If we just merge and then ignore any branch at all, wouldn't it be the same as squash and rebase?  Having one extra merge commit is the same shape when we ignore any branch (just a straight line), compared to if we just squash all the commits into one and rebase.

Comment: *do we really do binary search to find a new bug using automated build and automated test in practice?* I don't know: do you? (This would seem to depend on who "we" might be. :-) )

Comment: @torek because while I heard about it, I have never seen any company do it really

Comment: We haven't automated it, but we have done it manually. Bugs haven't been common enough yet to go any further - our CI system keeps people from committing anything too terrible.

Comment: Well the main difference between a non merge commit resulting from a squash of 7 commits, and a merge commit resulting from a feature branch with 7 commits, is that the former is not a merge commit.  Instead, it is a single logical commit made directly to your master branch, with only a single parent.  There are advantages to having a linear history, which is one reason you might lean towards the former option.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but I think if we ignore any branch and look at the straight line, it is exactly the same merge vs squash and rebase

Comment: Yes, it is, from that point of view, following the main parent path going back.  But, a merge commit is definitely not the same as rebasing a single squashed commit.  Another important difference: If you discover that a given merge commit brought in the problems, you can always hop over to that feature branch, which contains an audit of every work step taken, and try to figure out what happened.  With the squash commit, in theory, that resolution is lost forever.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, so the merged version gives more information. But it also is known as merge or branch hell... I guess it doesn't have to be that way if just ignoring the branches.  I think not squashing the commits also has one advantage: when the "buggy" commit was found, it can be 5 lines of code found, instead of 7 commits squashed together, and say if it is 62 lines or 89 lines of code, then it is harder to see how the bug was introduced. But not squashing the commits, then each commit has to have "good working condition"

Comment: Yes, that's basically what my comment above says.  It is also about having more fine-grain resolution in the Git history.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a question which has really been a long debate between those in the merge camp and those in the rebase camp.  The ideal answer here in my view is to lean towards using rebasing, but to endeavor to always make sure that each commit which is pushed is fully functional (i.e. all unit and integration tests pass).

It doesn't really make much of a difference whether you use a merge or rebase type workflow, from the point of view of discovering a bug.  In either case, most likely many commits have already been made since the bug commit was introduced.  In either workflow, you would fix the bug by making one or more commits which solves the problem.  The advantage of rebase, as you have correctly pointed out, is that `git bisect` can be used to drill down to the exact commit which introduced the bug.  In the case of a merge workflow, `git bisect` would still tell you which commit introduced the bug.  However, you might lose a lot of resolution in this case.  Instead of having a small functional commit, with a relatively small change set, you might have a large merge commit, which was generated by a feature branch containing many commits.  So, it could be harder to immediately figure out exactly *what* in that merge commit caused the problem.

I prefer a rebase workflow wherever possible, because it maintains a clean record of the exact steps taken to build a feature.

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow is to squash to a single commit and then rebase, you might as well just merge instead so you can retain the resolution. With "first-parent" view (which is the formal name for what you're calling "ignore any branch") the diffs between each merge commit should be identical to the squash/rebase history. Keeping the developers' preferred commit history from their feature branches is especially valuable if your workflow deletes feature branches once they are merged into master (or develop). Of course you don't need the extra commits, but sometimes it's nice to be able to follow along the train of thought of the development process.

Typically bugs are more likely to be found at the broken *line of code* rather than at the *commit*, so I wouldn't value the additional commits for the sole purpose of finding bugs, unless it's automated. If you intend to automate git bisect (or another binary search) by checking out and building specific commits, then ranking from easiest to hardest to automate would be: rebase without squash would be best, merge would be second best, and squash/rebase would be worst (because each commit would contain many changes with no resolution into individual commits). Note that you can still automate the isolation of the individual commit with merge, except that it's more complicated since you navigate first parent until you find the merge commit that breaks, and then trace down the second parent until you find the specific broken commit.

I personally prefer merge over rebase, but with a slight twist. One downside of merge, although rare, is that it's possible that there is no bug in the feature branch, and it's actually the merge commit that introduces the bug, even with no conflicts when the merge occurred. To prevent this, I advise my team to always rebase their feature branch onto the target first, and then merge in with --no-ff to force a merge commit. (This is sometimes called a semi-linear merge.)

Answer (score 0):

If you squash commits, it matters little whether you rebase or merge.  They will produce identical trees because the changes will be the same.  If you use a fully featured Git server like GitHub, you'll find that the squash workflow is referred to as "squash and merge", but the behavior is identical.

The benefit to not squashing, as you've noticed, is that you can bisect the change that introduced a bug with great precision.  However, you can also do this with a regular merge workflow that doesn't squash, because `git bisect` knows how to handle merge commits just fine.

In order to gain a real benefit from this extra history, you generally have to have a workflow that has sane, logical, bisectable commits.  If you have a lot of what we call "fixup commits" that fix syntax errors or other mistakes and don't enforce sane, logical commits, then `git bisect` will have a harder time tracking down the problematic commit because some commits won't even build.  So you do have to enforce this policy in code review and potentially even in CI if you want to adopt it.  The benefit of squashing instead is that developers can be lazy, but at the cost of potentially huge, inscrutable code dumps as single commits.

When working on Git, we do indeed frequently use `git bisect` to track down problematic commits.  I've also used it at a former workplace to track down where we introduced regressions, so this is a widely used approach.  However, some projects don't care about where something was broken and don't use reverts, so they don't use `git bisect` much.  It depends on your project and workflow, as well as the culture of your team.

Once approach I have seen that works is to require either sane, logical, bisectable commits or squashing.  If you are a careful, methodical developer who is willing to rebase and get the commits right before merge, then you can merge them outright; if you want to be lazy, then you have to squash.  This preserves the bisectability of the branch while making things easier for less fastidious developers.  This approach can also be done with rebase instead, if you prefer.

My general approach is the Git approach (which shouldn't be a surprise because I contribute to Git): rebase feature branches into sane, logical commits, and then create a merge commit.  But ultimately, you have to pick the workflow that works for your team.